# Setting Home Directory to `/home`

Tags: linux, gentoo

I have a single user system and I want to set my home directory not to `/home/username`, but to `/home`. How can I do it so nothing would blow up?

It would be fine, if the solution would avoid something like linking `/home/username` to `/home`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm the only user of my Kubuntu laptop and my Debian router; still I use `/home/kamil`. IMO changing the default is not worth the hassle, unless you have a good reason (but then compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). Let's suppose you did the change and everything works. Then you install a program that uses `/home/$USER` where it should use `$HOME`. Or it adds a non-system user for whatever reason and takes a subdirectory of `/home` over. Or you want to create another user to test something. My point is the idea may backfire in the future. Maintenance burden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `usermod` command:

> -d, --home HOME_DIR
>        The user's new login directory.
>        If the -m option is given, the contents of the current home directory will be moved to the new home directory, which is created if it does not already exist.

Otheriwse, I agree with Kamil's comment, you are probably shooting yourself in the foot, and if you want to avoid a directory level, `/username` would probably be a better idea since that leaves `/home` available.

Answer (score 1):

1. Warning: one problem with setting /home as a main_user1's HOME is that such user may trample over the content of /home/other_user2/ and /home/other_user3/
2. Adding to the answer form @xenoid, it is likely necessary to identify and update the ~/.bashrc and other scripts that may set the value of $HOME environment variable.
3. The reason for your desire to set a non-conventional directory would be useful for a possibly better alternative.

I would likely create a link /myhome -> /home/my_userid

And invoke some programs like this:

```
HOME=/myhome XYZ_program
```

Which exports the desired variable and value only to the program being spawn.